# Phonekeypad string to number

Tags: java, string, loops, for-loop

There is international keypad for phones and it's look like:

[image]

My program do the following:

- Convert the string to number e.g `ABC` equal to `1`
- Display result.

And I'm doing it like below:

```
private static String getNumber(String s) {

    String result = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        if (s.charAt(i) == 'A' || s.charAt(i) == 'B' || s.charAt(i) == 'C')
            result += "2";
        else if (s.charAt(i) == 'D' || s.charAt(i) == 'E' || s.charAt(i) == 'F')
            result += "3";
        else if (s.charAt(i) == 'G' || s.charAt(i) == 'H' || s.charAt(i) == 'I')
            result += "4";
        else if (s.charAt(i) == 'J' || s.charAt(i) == 'K' || s.charAt(i) == 'L')
            result += "5";
        else if (s.charAt(i) == 'M' || s.charAt(i) == 'N' || s.charAt(i) == 'O')
            result += "6";
        else if (s.charAt(i) == 'P' || s.charAt(i) == 'Q' || s.charAt(i) == 'R' || s.charAt(i) == 'S')
            result += "7";
        else if (s.charAt(i) == 'T' || s.charAt(i) == 'U' || s.charAt(i) == 'V')
            result += "8";
        else if (s.charAt(i) == 'W' || s.charAt(i) == 'X' || s.charAt(i) == 'Y' || s.charAt(i) == 'Z')
            result += "9";
        else
            result += s.charAt(i);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Sample input: `1-800-Flowers`

Output : `1-800-3569377`

**Question:**

Can i shorthand this code with for loop or something?

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of ways to accomplish this result, you can use [replace()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence)) to get the number you want:

```
public static String getNumber(String s) {
    // Set all String to caps
    s = s.toUpperCase();

    // Replace the letters with the corresponding numbers
    s = s.replaceAll("(A|B|C)", "2");
    s = s.replaceAll("(D|E|F)", "3");
    s = s.replaceAll("(G|H|I)", "4");
    s = s.replaceAll("(J|K|L)", "5");
    s = s.replaceAll("(M|N|O)", "6");
    s = s.replaceAll("(P|Q|R|S)", "7");
    s = s.replaceAll("(T|U|V)", "8");
    s = s.replaceAll("(W|X|Y|Z)", "9");

    return s;

}
```